# medium value mtrix

Tags: matlab, logic

I am new in matlab and i can't find the appropriate code to do the following.

I have this matrix (2 columns):

```
3,2348  265
2,2281  305
2,9321  315
3,6374  315
3,9069  355
1,8879  45
2,5944  45
3,3011  45
3,7679  95
4,1550  135
2,7442  135
4,1066  185
2,1129  185
1,7600  205
3,0655  225
```

and i would like to convert it in this (2 columns):

```
2,5945  45
3,7680  95
3,4497  135
3,1098  185
1,7601  205
3,0656  225
3,2349  265
2,2281  305
3,2849  315
3,9070  355
```

The objective is that in matrix1, for each repeated value in col2 we do the mean of the correspondent values in col1.

For example for line 1 , for `45` (col2)--> `col1=(1,8880+2,5944+3,3012)/3` = `2,5945`

Comment: Where you getting your values from, 1,8880+2,5944+3,3012)/3?

Answer (score 3):

This is a good job for [accumarray](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html):

```
A = [32348 265
     22281 305
     29321 315
     36374 315]; %# fill the rest of the matrix
[indices,ix] = sort(A(:,2),'ascend'); %# sort col2 in ascending order
data = A(ix,1); %# sort the values (col1) in the same way
groups = unique(indices);
mean_value = accumarray(indices, data, [numel(groups) 1], @mean);
%# the 4-argument version lets you specify a function to use (@mean in this case)

new_A = [mean_value groups]; %# this is the desired output
```

For more reading, check out [this blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/02/20/under-appreciated-accumarray/).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
%A is the input matrix that you describe
A = [32348 265
     22281 305
     29321 315
     36374 315
     ...]

unique_values = unique(A(:, 2));
output = zeros(length(unique_values), 2);
for i=1:length(unique_values)
  output(i, 1) = mean(A(A(:, 2) == unique_values(i), 1));
end
output(:, 2) = unique_values;
```

`unique(A(:, 2))` finds the unique values in the second column. The `for` loop finds the average for each of these unique values.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest code I could come up with (*A* is your input matrix):

```
A = sortrows(A,2);
[B,i,j] = unique(A(:,2));
A = [accumarray(j,A(:,1),size(i),@mean),B];
```